# Is there a technique to make VS Code autocomplete suggestions look like Atom's autocomplete menu?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, atom-editor

I want to make VS Code's autocomplete menu look like Atom's autocomplete menu. Is there an extension/workaround for this?
This is the Atom menu:

[image: Atom Autocomplete]

and this is VS Code:

[image: VS Code autocomplete]

Comment: Use `Ctr+Space` to see more of the snippet in the suggestion box

Comment: I too have been searching for an extension like that. I talked to one of my friends who knows how to make extensions and he told that vscode still doesn't have that feature to be able to edit the looks of suggestions lists. But it was like 4 months ago, and I am not sure about is the feature now available or not. I will inform you as soon as possible when I find something.

Comment: According to this issue https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/150329.
Vscode has API for it but someone need to create extension and use that api.